# Prove that the following singular symmetric matrix is of rank $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> Let $$A=\pmatrix{x&a&b\\a&y&c\\b&c&z}$$ be a symmetric matrix (over $\mathbb{R}$ if necessary) such that $\det A=0$ and that
>   $$\left|\matrix{x&a\\a&y}\right|+\left|\matrix{x&b\\b&z}\right|+\left|\matrix{y&c\\c&z}\right|=0$$
>   (those $2\times2$ matrices are obtained from $A$ by erasing the diagonal elements). Prove that $\operatorname{rank}A\leq 1$.

---

My attempts: (1) There are $6$ variables and $2$ equations, leaving $4$ degrees of freedom, which is already a bad thing. (2) I wrote down the Laplace extension into the complementary minors, and tried to prove that all the complementary minors are equal to $0$ (which would imply that desired result), but at the end I got $6$ minors versus $4$ equations:
$$m_{11}+m_{22}+m_{33}=0$$
$$xm_{11}-ym_{22}-zm_{33}+2cm_{23}=0$$
$$xm_{11}-ym_{22}+zm_{33}+2bm_{13}=0$$
$$-xm_{11}-ym_{22}+zm_{33}+2am_{23}=0$$
where $m_{ij}$ denotes the determinant of $A$ substracting the $i$th row and the $j$th column.

Comment: Can you use Sylvester's Law?

Comment: @AHusain I don’t know what I’m allowed to use. All answers are welcomed :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ has zero as eigenvalue, its characteristic polynomial is $$\lambda^3-\mathrm{tr}(A)\lambda^2 +\alpha \lambda ,$$
where $\mathrm{tr}(A)=x+y+z$ and $\alpha$ is to be determined. We need to show that $\alpha =0$. But actually, if you do the computation of $\det (\lambda I -A)$ you will see 
$$-\alpha= \left|\matrix{x&a\\a&y}\right|+\left|\matrix{x&b\\b&z}\right|+\left|\matrix{y&c\\c&z}\right|=0.$$
And we're done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. some question: (1) How does $\alpha=0$ imply that $\operatorname{rank}A=1$? (the algebraic multiplicity of $0$ would be $2$, but generally that doesn't mean that the geometric multiplicity of $0$ is also $2$). (2) Is there a more general fact (for any size of $A$ of the last expression of $\alpha$ in term of the minors?

Comment: @BQT Nice question. The matrix in question is symmetric, so it is diagonalizable. In particular the geometric and algebraic multiplicities do agree.

Comment: @BQT For the second question, yes it does hold in general.

Comment: Yes of course; since the terms in $det(A-\lambda I)$ that are linear in $\lambda$ are exactly those having $1$ diagonal factor. Great answer.